# Parallel Port Access in Matlab

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I'm having difficulties accessing a parallel port on Ubuntu 22.04. It is a SUNIX Co. Multiport MIO6469A that was installed in a PCI slot. It has both DB-9 (serial) and DB-25 (parallel) connectors. We're trying to use it to send signals via parallel port to an EEG system in Matlab. But the codes are not being recieved.

How can I tell if the parallel port has been installed/configured correctly on Linux?

Quick summary: In the terminal, if type `-lspci -vv`, the PCI card seems to be found (see below). But I'm confused for a few reasons. First, it's showing a serial port, not a parallel port. Second, we're having trouble using the 'ppdev_mex.m' function in Matlab, which is commonly used for this kind of thing. So I'm not sure if we have the right address for parallel port.

Any help is appreciated!

```
0000:04:00.0 Communication controller [0708]: SUNIX Co., Ltd. Multiport serial controller
    Subsystem: SUNIX Co., Ltd. Multiport serial controller
    Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: I/O ports at 3020 [size=32]
    Region 1: I/O ports at 3048 [size=8]
    Region 2: I/O ports at 3040 [size=8]
    Region 3: I/O ports at 3000 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: parport_serial
    Kernel modules: parport_serial
```

When I run `sudo adduser <username> lp`, it suggests that I am already a member of the `lp` group. How do I check who is a member?

`journalctl -xb | grep parport` returns

```
Jan 30 20:00:12 McRey57-LN-01 systemd-modules-load[442]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Jan 30 20:00:12 McRey57-LN-01 kernel: parport_serial 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0001)
Jan 30 20:00:12 McRey57-LN-01 kernel: parport0: PC-style at 0x3048 (0x3040), irq 16, using FIFO [PCSPP,TRISTATE,COMPAT,EPP,ECP]
```

`ls -l /dev/lp*` returns

```
lp: cannot access '/dev/lp*': No such file or directory
```

`id` returns:

```
uid=1001(gaspelingroup) gid=1001(gaspelingroup) groups=1001(gaspelingroup),4(adm),7(lp),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),122(lpadmin),135(lxd),136(sambashare),1002(psychtoolbox)
```

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt says parallel ports should show up as /dev/lp*

Comment: Anything helpful in `journalctl -xb | grep parport` or `grep parport /var/log/dmesg`?

Comment: Does your UID have `rw` access to `/dev/lp*`? Do `ls -l /dev/lp*` and `id`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: @NickG You can check who is a member of the group by following the last part of waltinator's comment. If it's not as expected, then remember you need to reboot or relog after adduser

Comment: @Daniel T: See update #3 in original post.  Command doesn't appear to work.

Comment: @NickG Specifically, waltinator said to use `id` to check which groups you are in. Notice the spelling id vs lp. Also if `/dev/lp*` fails it just means the kernel didn't find a parallel port

Comment: @Daniel T: See update #4 in original post.  I am a member of the `lp` group.  See also update #1.

Comment: @NickG Please post the lspci output with `lspci -vnvn` this time. Please also add `parport_serial.dyndbg=+p` inside `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` and do `sudo update-grub` and `reboot`. Then look for new messages in `dmesg` related to https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/parport/parport_serial.c It's strange that I can't find your MIO6469A in that file

Comment: @DanielT: quick question. After some research, this is a PCIe card.  That means it won’t work with the parallel port, correct?

Comment: @NickG That is not correct. The whole purpose of the parport_serial driver is to support PCI(e) cards with parallel ports and serial ports mixed together

Comment: Just to be clear, if I bought a parallel port on this list, would things work?

Comment: @NickG Looking at the kernel source, it implies that MIO5099A is supported. But it's almost $100, so I would try my answer with the udev and modprobe thing I found on the internet first.

Answer (score 0):

I found an [untested solution](https://forum.linuxcnc.org/18-computer/44964-sunix-pci-parallel-port-chips-and-cards-linux) and adapted it:

1. Create a file named `/etc/modprobe.d/sunix-askubuntu-1501881.conf` containing the following:

   ```
   alias parport_low_level parport_pc
   options parport_pc io=0x3020 irq=11,auto
   ```
2. Create a file named `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-sunix-askubuntu-1501881.rules` containing the following:

   ```
   ATTR{device}=="0x1999", ATTR{vendor}=="0x1fd4", RUN+="/sbin/modprobe parport_low_level"
   ```
3. Reboot

If the parallel port doesn't show up or work, try replacing the 0x3020, with 0x3048, 0x3040, then 0x3000, with a reboot in between. If the kernel crashes or if you get a conflict, add `install parport_serial /bin/false` to the first file.

Comment: This solution did not work.  We tried all the combinations at the bottom.

Comment: @NickG Oh well. You might as well buy the MIO5099A, or a 5x cheaper USB alternative. If you're still looking for a software solution, you could try editing and recompiling the parport_serial.c file then email the kernel mailing list

Comment: Alright, I'll be working with other sources for a solution.